# Python: What "security restrictions" are you disabling when you enable `huge_tree` argument in lxml.etree.XMLParser?

Tags: python, lxml

As far as I can tell from the [lxml library documentation](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.XMLParser), setting `huge_tree` argument to `True` does "disable security restrictions and support very deep trees and very long text content (only affects libxml2 2.7+)".

I understand that this seems to be suited for parsing very long and/or very complicated ("deep") XML documents but I do not understand what are the "security restrictions" in question and I could not find it in the code either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a breadcrumb for your answer might be found in the FAQ:

> This has nothing to do with lxml itself, only with the parser of libxml2. Since libxml2 version 2.7, the parser imposes hard security limits on input documents to prevent DoS attacks with forged input data. Since lxml 2.2.1, you can disable these limits with the `huge_tree` parser option if you need to parse *really* large, trusted documents. All lxml versions will leave these restrictions enabled by default.
>
> Note that libxml2 versions of the 2.6 series do not restrict their parser and are therefore vulnerable to DoS attacks.

https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#is-lxml-vulnerable-to-xml-bombs

According to [CHANGES.txt](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/d01872ccdf7e1e5e825b6c6292b43e7d27ae5fc4/CHANGES.txt) in the `lxml` repo, `huge_tree` has existed since June 2009.

## Digging a little deeper into libxml2:

It appears the Python bindings set `XML_PARSE_HUGE` in the C parser's flag set.

See `src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd` [here](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/d01872ccdf7e1e5e825b6c6292b43e7d27ae5fc4/src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd#L175) or, in libxml2 [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/c9925454fd384a17c8c03d358c6778a552e9287b/parser.c#L126) for examples.

Since these limits appear to measure the size of consecutive expansions (rate of growth) and such limits on linear growth were introduced in particular versions of libxml2, that's one area where `huge_tree=False` claims to add some protections.